# Creating a new jsp page in eclipse for my solr application

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, solr

I'm following this tutorial http://www.lucidimagination.com/devzone/technical-articles/setting-apache-solr-eclipse but I can't see my new page when I create one in the src folder.

I want to create a new jsp file (base.jsp) in the eclipse src folder which will then appear here: http://localhost:8080/solr/base.jsp

The tutorial said to change the build path output to TestSolr/webapp/WEB-INF/classes so I have tried http://localhost:8080/solr0/classes/base.jsp as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the java source files would go into the src folder.
If you have exploded the apache war file and and copied the contents into the webapp folder in eclipse, place the base.jsp file into the webapp folder.
The file basically should be at the root in the same location as index.jsp.